How to download old version library?
hello In the java source code of an old Android Studio project from ExoPlayer version 2.10.6 Used, Gerdle can't download this version, I can't edit the codes, I can't find the file aar, what should I do?

These versions were only available via Bintray which had been shut down. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.exoplayer/exoplayer?repo=bt-google-exoplayer
